# Using bash to get the files rar creates

Tags: bash, compression

I'm running the command

```
rar a -m0 -v100m rarname.rar *.*
```

On some files with a bash script. I know I specified the rarname, but because of the -v option which sets a size limit to the rar, this command can make lots of rars named rarname.part1.rar, rarname.part2.rar, etc.

What is the best way to get the list of files created?

Comment: It's slightly off-topic, but be aware that *.* won't catch all files in the directory when creating the rar. Using * will.

Comment: i know that (: it was just an example. in my script i'm getting all the files individually to rar them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
rarname.*.rar
```

Globs are not limited to the DOS-style "name.ext" pattern.

Comment: the rarname variable could have ".rar" at the end of it.

Comment: Then use rarname.*rar instead.

Comment: if rarname contains '.rar' at the end it will actually be searching for rarname.rar.*.rar or rarname.rar.*rar

Answer (score 0):

You can either capture and parse the output from the `rar` command or create the rar'ed files in a temporary directory, and then process the files there.

I'd recommend the later option.